# What is the best way to speed up app doing sentiment analysis on 100 tweets?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am creating an app that returns 100 tweets from Twitter's API and then does sentiment analysis on all 100 tweets. The following method is called when a user types in a query of interest and the browser make a request to '/get_tweets'.

```
def get_tweets
  tweets = $twitter.search(query_params, count: 100).attrs[:statuses]
  @tweets = []
  datumbox = Datumbox.create('2ef48d67598553804617c9862dfcaf8f')
  tweets.each do |t|
    tweet = Tweet.new
    tweet.twitter_id = t[:id_str]
    tweet.text = t[:text]
    tweet.user_id = t[:user][:id_str]
    tweet.name = t[:user][:name]
    tweet.screen_name = t[:user][:screen_name]
    tweet.location = t[:user][:location]
    tweet.profile_image_url = t[:user][:profile_image_url_https]
    tweet.tweet_created_at = t[:created_at]

    # Need to remove @ symbols to use datumbox API analysis
    sentiment_text = tweet.text.gsub(/@/,'')
    tweet.sentiment = datumbox.twitter_sentiment_analysis(text: sentiment_text)
    @tweets << tweet
  end
  render :index
end
```

The problem is that this is extremely slow. All is all when the user types in his/her query of interest this method does 101 API calls.

What is the best approach to speed this up? Is there a design approach to consider when building apps that need to make a "large" number of API calls? In the end, I want to display the tweets to the user in a tab format where they can switch between positive, neutral and negative tweets. Should I maybe think about doing calls to the sentiment analysis API in batches?

Suggestions are much appreciated!

Comment: This question is too broad and opinion based for stackoverflow. I'm going to give you a few hints as to where to start looking though.
Potential solutions could be to use [parallelism to do several API requests at once](https://github.com/typhoeus/typhoeus) or getting the sentiment analysis asynchronously. But you are going to hit the 1000 requests/day limit in no time, so you will need to create your own service running the [Datumbox Machine Learning Framework](http://www.datumbox.com/machine-learning-framework/).

Comment: I thought about doing synchronous analysis, but then the user is still waiting around for the tweet to get organized into the appropriate tabs. I think parallelism might be a potential solution. Also am going to have to figure out how to create my own service. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Possible approaches:

1. Process the tweets in the background beforehand so that the user is not querying the Twitter API in real time, just your database of pre-processed ones.
2. Use AJAX so that the page is not reloaded in its entirety. You can show a loading indicator, which will show the user something is happening.
3. Don't get 100 tweets all at once. Do them one at a time and send each one to the user as it is processed by keeping the connection open. You could look at [ActionController::Live](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Live.html) for this, or some sort of [WebSockets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) implementation. Your javascript would have an event handler to put each processed tweet into your UI as it arrives.